# Why does a concept of safe integer exists in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have observed some weird stuff in native javascript on my chrome inspector console. For example, I ran this

`var a = 10208629303283853; 
 var b = 10208629303283855; 
 console.log(a); 
 console.log(b);`

which gives the result

`10208629303283852
10208629303283856`

Why there is a difference in value. On googling, I found that the above numbers are out of safe limit (refer to link below). That may cause it to behave abnormally. Why does a concept like this exists? and Why does var allows us to store the large number in the first place?

Source -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: it's more of a safe integer concept in floating point numbers, but it exists, because, well, there is a safe integer range - `Why does var allows us to store the large number in the first place? ` because 64bit floating point allows larger numbers

Comment: Then answer is in the article you linked: *JavaScript uses double-precision floating-point format numbers as specified in IEEE 754*. Standards are to provide reliable and consistent performance across different platforms and environment, including data interchange. It's not just about ECMAScript. If you're wondering why *MAX_SAFE_INTEGER* exists, it's (probably) so you can easily test if values exceed it and decide what to do, rather then having to remember it's `9007199254740991` and setting larger values to *Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY* or *NaN* or whatever.